# Search JabRef from terminal

Tags: terminal, bibtex

**Context:** In the JabRef GUI you can search your database.

**Question:** How can I do this from terminal without opening JabRef?

**Example:** What would I enter at terminal to print all entries in `example.bib` with the author `Turing` or with `avacado` in the title?

Answer (score 0):

JabRef has a command-line feature built in to display all entries using the `-m` option:

```
JabRef.jar -m (author=Turing or title=avacado) -n references.bib
```

The `-n` option disables the GUI.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Thomas. 
Trying this from the directory where references.bib lives returned `JabRef.jar: command not found`
I've tried various combinations without the `.jar` and with lower case letters but no luck. Any ideas?